# Can I take as a value iframe .php from from external .php?

Tags: php, ajax, html

I have a php page that calls a php iframe, the iframe php executes a series of actions that return a response or value.

As I can take that answer from the external php page (which calls the iframe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions, the easiest is that from the iframe php save the value in a session variable (_SESSION) and from the external php, ajax make a constantly read that session variable (_SESSION).

This way you take any value that does or calculate the iframe.